# Contact Form 7 not sending in WordPress 3.7.2

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

is anyone having this problem? just won't send. the form says sent, but i do not receive anything.

i found a couple of threads and tried some of the suggestions but still not working

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/cant-send-e-mail-from-my-wordpress-site

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-371-compatibility

Comment: Do you get any emails from your wordpress installation?  For example, when you try to reset your password.

Comment: just added a new user, no email sent/received.. hmmm

Comment: Doesn't sound like it an issue with Contact Form 7 specifically. Is this installed on your local computer? A web host?  Many hosts do not provide reliable email service.

Comment: its on my server cloud server which has other Wordpress sites although they are not using 3.7.1 - i'm thinking i need to roll back

Comment: Wordpress uses php's basic mail() function, I believe.  You can write a quick test script to see if everything is working properly: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Also check you `spam` folder.

Comment: i just tried this and loaded the file in the browser and received nothing (i used my own email address)...

<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>

Comment: `<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>`

Comment: not in spam folder either

Comment: Did you change the email addresses in the example?  Unless your email address is `nobody@example.com`, you'll never get it.

Comment: i did still didn't work. just phone the hosting company to look into this for me....

Answer (score 2):

I installed the WP SMTP plugin, and checked "Use the PHP mail() function to send emails."
After that everything worked again.

Answer (score 1):

Though the Contact Form 7 plugin successfully sends millions of emails every day, there are a host of issues that can stop or delay emails on both the sending and receiving ends. It depends entirely on your local Server & WordPress configuration.

You will need to investigate this issue for your particular local configuration. See [Contact Form 7 Email Issues & Problems](https://blog.cf7skins.com/contact-form-7-email-issues/).

Answer (score 1):

I just got done debugging this issue for someone. My process was

- Use a script to test the php mail() function https://www.conetix.com.au/support/article/simple-php-mail-test
- Use a script to test the wp_mail function https://gist.github.com/butlerblog/5c9b805529c419b81447
- Turn on wordpress debugging and sprinkle error_log in the contact form 7 code and see what's happening.

In my case, it was the weirdest thing. The contact form had a default value for the subject.

**[your-subject]**

For whatever reason, the php mail() function on my server would **NOT** send an email with that subject. Take out the dash, and it works fine. I'm betting that this is somehow related to how the mail() function is calling sendmail internally, but I haven't dug any deeper yet.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's mail() function may be disabled on your server. Try installing the WP SMTP plugin and using it instead.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smtp/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to installing a plugin for SMTP (smtp-wp, WP Mail SMTP, etc.), make sure that, in configuration of Contact Form 7, the text area "Message Body" contains at least the code "[your-message] "(without quotes).